# How can I disable Matlab's visual effects in the GUI?

Tags: matlab

I find those kind of effects annoying:

[image]

Is there any way to disable Matlab's visual effects in the GUI?

I use R2014a on Windows 7.

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.

Comment: Since this question received no answer, I posted it on Quora: https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-can-I-disable-Matlabs-visual-effects-in-the-GUI